Linear combination of weighed Laguerre polynomials is nonnegative when no coefficient is zero?
The motivation of this question is quantum physics. I am working on the Wigner function of some mixed state that is a convex combination of number states, i.e.
$$
\rho_M=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n\left|n\right\rangle\left\langle n\right|;\quad P_n\geq 0; \sum_nP_n=1\tag{1}. 
$$
The Wigner function is given by
$$
W_M(\alpha, \alpha^*) = \frac{e^{-2|\alpha|^2}}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n (-1)^n L_n(4|\alpha|^2) \tag{2}
$$
in the unit system of my choice.
I would like to interpret the Wigner function as a true probability distribution, which is justified since
$$
\int W(\alpha,\alpha^*)\mathrm{d}^2\alpha = 1 \tag{3} .
$$
This interpretation requires that $W$ is nonnegative everywhere. One question popping into my mind is

What kind of $P_n$ gives rise to a nonnegative $W_M$?


And so I tried several values for $P_n$. My first try was trying out $P_n$ for a thermal state
$$
P_n = \frac{\tilde{n}^n}{(1+\tilde{n})^{n+1}}\tag{4}
$$
where $\tilde{n}$ is the average quantum count. The Wigner function of a thermal state is well-known to be Gaussian, which is positive everywhere.


Then I tried a mixture of a finite number of number states, e.g. $P_n = 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1$ for $n=0, 4, 9, 13$. This time the Wigner function has a negative part.


Trying out a bunch of similar values, I notice one thing: $W_M$ is nonnegative when $P_n>0$ for all $n$, regardless of how $P_n$ is distributed. I think this is a plausible observation since well-known nonnegative Wigner functions are those with this property, e.g. thermal states, coherent states, and squeezed states. The only exception is the vacuum state, for which $P_0=1$ and $P_{n\neq 0}=0$, but we may argue that it is trivial considering Eq. (2). So physically, it seems like the Wigner function of a statistical mixture of number states is nonzero only if all number states are present in the mixture.

Why ask this on the Mathematics StackExchange? Because crossposting seems to be a bad practice and I suspect that it has something to do with how the Laguerre polynomials serve as bases in the function space over which they are orthonormal (I am not familiar with the rigorous notion, pardon my ignorance). As it stands, Eq. (2) contains every member of the set $\left(e^{-x/2}(-1)^nL_n(x)\right)_{n=0}^\infty$ which is orthonormal in $L^2(0, +\infty)$. Treating the set as the basis for the function space of $W_M$ for $|\alpha|\in[0,+\infty]$, my guess translates to
$$
f(x) = e^{-x/2}\sum_n a_n (-1)^nL_n(x)\geq 0\quad \mathrm{if} \quad a_n>0;a_n\in\mathbb{R};\ \sum_n a_n=1 
$$
(note that I have used $>$ instead of $\geq$, contary to my previous deleted question, as some may have seen). That is, a convex combination of the "Laguerre bases" containing all bases are nonnegative.
I have spent a bit too much time looking through the literature in vain, so I would be very grateful if someone could tell me if this is a known result in mathematics, or if I am just plain wrong.

Interpreting  the Wigner function as a true probability distribution is bound to fail, from the general theory of Wigner functions, whether such are positive semidefinite or not! They fail Kolmogorov's third axiom...
